# How to receive external emails on email server

Tags: email, debian, raspberry-pi, postfix, dovecot

So far I have an email server set up using postfix / dovecot on a raspberry pi (debian). I can send emails externally and internally no problem however can only receive emails from within my server.

I think it is because I have everything setup for TLS but do not have a valid certificate yet for my server however in order to get a valid certificate, I need a valid email address for my server (admin@myserver.com). Kind of a loop I am stuck in if I need an email address for the cert and require a cert for the email address!

For this reason, how can I temporarily allow my server to accept connections and emails NOT requiring TLS (essentially no security until I get my cert)? Is this the right way to go at it? Perhaps I am in left field, but all I am trying for is to receive emails....

Here is my setup below:

[image]

My main.cf file:

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default    
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
#smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/ssl/caroot.crt
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

myhostname = finendale.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = localhost, finendale.com, localhost.finendale.com
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_password
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
relayhost = [relay.dynu.com]:2525
smtp_generic_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/generic
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
permit_sasl_authenticated,
 permit_mynetworks,
 reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = 
permit_mynetworks,
permit_sasl_authenticated,
reject_invalid_helo_hostname,
reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname,
reject_unknown_help_hostname
check_helo_access hash:/etc/postfix/helo_access
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
#smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
home_mailbox = Maildir/
```

My master.cf file:

```
#
# Postfix master process configuration file.  For details on the format
# of the file, see the master(5) manual page (command: "man 5 master").
#
# Do not forget to execute "postfix reload" after editing this file.
#
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
2525      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       1       postscreen
#smtpd     pass  -       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#dnsblog   unix  -       -       -       -       0       dnsblog
#tlsproxy  unix  -       -       -       -       0       tlsproxy
submission inet n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
#  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
smtps     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
 -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
 -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject 
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#628       inet  n       -       -       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    fifo  n       -       -       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       -       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      fifo  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     fifo  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       -       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       -       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       -       -       1       verify 
flush     unix  n       -       -       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       -       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       -       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       -       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       -       -       1       scache
#
# ====================================================================
# Interfaces to non-Postfix software. Be sure to examine the manual
# pages of the non-Postfix software to find out what options it wants.
#
# Many of the following services use the Postfix pipe(8) delivery
# agent.  See the pipe(8) man page for information about ${recipient}
# and other message envelope options.
# ====================================================================
#
# maildrop. See the Postfix MAILDROP_README file for details.
# Also specify in main.cf: maildrop_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Recent Cyrus versions can use the existing "lmtp" master.cf entry.
#
# Specify in cyrus.conf:
#   lmtp    cmd="lmtpd -a" listen="localhost:lmtp" proto=tcp4 
#
# Specify in main.cf one or more of the following:
#  mailbox_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#  virtual_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Cyrus 2.1.5 (Amos Gouaux)
# Also specify in main.cf: cyrus_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
#cyrus     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -r ${sender} -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
# Old example of delivery via Cyrus.
#
#old-cyrus unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=R user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# See the Postfix UUCP_README file for configuration details.
#
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
#
# Other external delivery methods.
#
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -   n   n   -   2   pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> I think it is because I have everything setup for TLS but do not have a valid certificate yet

You should first check Postfix logs – and your firewall logs – to make sure that actually *is* the problem.

> For this reason, how can I temporarily allow my server to accept connections and emails NOT requiring TLS (essentially no security until I get my cert)?

That depends on how Dynu delivers mail to you. Note that according to your diagram and DNS records, your server is not supposed to receive any direct connections from mail senders, *only* from the Dynu relay.

Your diagram says that you've configured Dynu to relay mail to your server on port 465. Because it's an TLS-only port, you must first check the configuration at Dynu to not *expect* a valid certificate. Depending on what options it offers, either configure the Dynu service to accept invalid certificates (which you already have), or to relay mail on a different port (port 2525 is non-TLS in your configuration).

- If Dynu is configured to deliver mail to port 465 on your server, the existing self-signed certificate should work well enough to speak TLS.
- If Dynu is configured to deliver mail to port 2525 on your server, remove the "require TLS" parameters that you've added, specifically `smtpd_use_tls`. Actually, it **should not** be set globally in the first place – different ports have different requirements on whether to enforce TLS. (Note how the 'submission' and 'smtps' services already have `-o` option lines to enforce TLS per port.)

> [image]

Note that the certificate's name needs to match the actual (sub)domain that other SMTP clients are connecting to – it is *not* compared against the @domain in your email address. It is fine if both are identical in your case, but for most people's domains they aren't.

In direct delivery, the certificate would need to match the name in MX records. For example, if you had `MX 0 mail.finendale.com.`, you would need a cert for "mail.finendale.com".

But because you're only receiving mail via the Dynu relay, the certificate needs to match whatever hostname is entered within Dynu's configuration.

> Here is my setup below

The port labels in the diagram don't make sense. Your domain doesn't receive mail on any port nor forward it on any other port. The MX records on finendale.com instead tell senders to *directly* deliver inbound mail to `mx1.dynu.com` port 25.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. So I have hashed out smtpd_use_tls and redirected dynu to 2525 (temporarily). Viewing mail.log shows mx1.dynu.com connects then disconnects, without any errors this time (better than before) but I don't see any emails pop up in the folders I set up. If it just shows "connect" then "disconnect" does that mean that postfix did its job? If so then what else could be stopping the mail from reaching its folders?

Comment: If Postfix does not log a queue entry, then there was no message sent. In this case it's more likely something specific to how Dynu performs relaying.